# How can I detect screen unlock with React Native?

Tags: react-native

Does anyone know a way in which I can detect when the user has opened their phone? To my understanding android.intent.USER_PRESENT is broadcast when the device is unlocked (e.g. correct password entered), however, I do not know how to detect the broadcast in with React native. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I'm not aware of a bridge built yet, but if an event is emitted, you can listen for it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look into [AppState API in FB(Face Book)](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html)

It has 3 states on FB and 5 total. I only see 3 in FB but the other 2 may or may not be suppprted.

`Active` - The app is running in the foreground

`background` - The app is running in the background. The user is either in another app or on the home screen.

`inactive` - This is a state that occurs when transitioning between foreground & background, and during periods of inactivity such as entering the Multitasking view or in the event of an incoming call

Check out apples [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) for more on these.

You're going to have to test what state is hit when you the phone is in the lockscreen. I can't tell you what state to use because I have never tested the api out.

as you can see from the code below the test is done in a conditional statement

```
 if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active')
```

I'm taking facebooks example here but attach the `change` event listiner in `componentDidMount` and remove in `ComponentWillUnmount` and the code will run accourding to the state.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {AppState, Text} from 'react-native'

class AppStateExample extends Component {

  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground!')
    }
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>
    );
  }

}
```