# How restart android app after unlock screen

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react native app that use paho mqtt (react native module) the problem is that when the screen is lock, this service die. Im not android developer but I read that the problem is that doze mode kill all and my paho service die after a few minutes.

I read this issue https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.android/issues/226 and test a solution given there but in android > 8 this solution not work anymore.

I think 2 possible solutions:

```
1. Run service again after unlock the screen (dunno how to do this for
android >8).
2. Restart the app after unlock the screen (Searching for how detect that the screen is unlock in react native).
```

If someone know how to handle this solutions or another one.

Comment: Have you checked this answer here, a possible duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109675/how-can-i-detect-screen-unlock-with-react-native

Comment: Currently using this library. As per the previous comment, we kill the client when `appState` goes to the background, and reconnect it when the app comes into the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

For Android native, you can use [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

`A service is simply a component that can run in the background, even when the user is not interacting with your application, so you should create a service only if that is what you need.`

I know you are using react-native, but hope the info would provide some hints.

Comment: I'm using mqtt service the problem is that in doze mode (after 15 mins unlock mobile more or less) the service die and not comeback.

Comment: May be a custom solution what i did to deal with while developing a vehicle tracking service be helpful. I developed my own service and attached it to the sticky notification, and i used to deal with Mqtt stuffs through this parmanent running sticky service.

Comment: you have an example with that ?

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz the sample code in the link is a good place to start with, for example, https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#ExtendingService